# Create JSON from a String

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to create a json from this String

```
var json = { data: [v1,v2], con: [begin: "test1", end: "test2"] };
```

What is wrong with the String? I get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`It is not possible to set a key for the value test1 and test2?

Comment: `What is wrong with the String`. This is not a string.

Comment: It is not a string

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between JSON (a data format) and JavaScript (a programming language).

Comment: Are you really trying to start with a string. It needs to be in quotes "{ data: [v1,v2], con: [begin: 'test1', end: 'test2'] }";

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

An object literal, which uses the `{}` syntax, consists of a collection of `property: value` pairs.

An array literal, which uses the `[]` syntax, consists of a collection of `values`.

> ```
> [begin: "test1", end: "test2"]
> ```

You have used the array syntax here, but have tried to put `property: value` pairs inside it.

This causes your error, the `:` isn't expected.

You probably want to use the `{}` there. Alternatively, you want to remove `begin:` and `end:`.

---

This has nothing to do with JSON or strings. It is simply JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a javascript `Object`.

```
const toto = {};
```

is the same as

```
const toto = new Object();
```

---

This is a `String` javascript object, which hold a string representation of a json.

```
const toto = "{ \"key\": \"value\" }";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var json = { data: ["v1","v2"], con: [{begin: "test1"}, {end: "test2"}] };
```

It looks like you might have a blocking error.